# problems with array_reverse

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array, which is printed out. But it is printed in reverse order how I need. But when I try to use `array_reverse()` it outputs almost random values:

```
for($j=0; $j<count($positions);$j++){
    $temp[$j]=strlen($positions[$j]);
}
array_push($GLOBALS['lengths'],$temp);
```

and when I echo `$lengths` I get(as it should be, but in reverse order):

```
1 1
2 1
```

but when I use `array_reverse($GLOBALS['lengths'])` I get:

```
4 1
2 1
```

where might be the issue?

Thats the code that I use:

```
for($j=0; $j<count($positions);$j++){

    $temp[$j]=strlen($positions[$j]);
}
array_push($GLOBALS['lengths'],$temp);
$lengths=array_reverse($GLOBALS['lengths']);
```

Comment: Please show us the array declaration and what your goal is? Something like: this is the situation and this is my goal

Comment: Where is the code that outputs your array? What's the content of `$positions`? Is it an array of strings or an array of arrays? I noticed you are using `strlen` and not `count`.

Comment: try `array_reverse($GLOBALS['lengths'], true);` to preserve keys it will give a good hint.

Comment: @Rizier123 http://codepaste.net/tx5c9m
Firstly, I want to find the position of a given text in the string, and then to save that positions' length in the array `$lengths`

Comment: @Victory ,doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//this will reverse the result output
for($j=count($positions); $j>0; $j--){
    array_push($GLOBALS['lengths'],strlen($positions[$j-1]));
}
$lengths=$GLOBALS['lengths'];
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer, even though not working on my particular case, showed me, how to do it in another place :)